# Evaluate code block in Kotlin (to hide variables inside scope)

Tags: kotlin

In Scala, you can write

```
val x = {
  ... do some complex computations ..
  42
}
```

to hide stuff inside of the code block.

The closest I came in Kotlin is:

```
val x = {
  ... do some complex computations ..
  42
}()
```

Is there a better way?

EDIT:

- isn’t `run {}` in the above example essentially the same
- is calling run costly?

ANSWER:

- using `run {}` inlines, whereas `{}()` does NOT (see my own answer below)

Comment: "isn’t run {} in the above example essentially the same": It will give the same result, but the call to `run` is guaranteed to be inlined, while doing `{ ... }()` will create a function object and call it.

Comment: @marstran why is a function object created? Run is also just calling () on the passes lambda

Comment: Because `run` is an inline function. The lambda body is copied to the call site by the compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `run` function. It takes a function as a parameter, runs it and returns the result.

```
val x = run {
  ... do some complex computations ..
  42
}
```

The `run` function is inlined, so it will have no performance overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is the [run](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) function.

```
val x = run {
    ...
    42
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**And also you can use these methods too:**

```
 val a=1.also{
    // your code
}
val b=2.apply{
    // your code}
}
val c=3.let{
    // your code
}
val d=4.runCatching{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To verify inlining when using `run`, I created a small example:

```
    fun main() {
        {
            Math.random()
        }()

        run {
            Math.random()
        }
    }
```

and viewed the produced bytecode:

```
  public final static main()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 2 L0
    GETSTATIC TestKt$main$1.INSTANCE : LTestKt$main$1;
    CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function0
    INVOKEINTERFACE kotlin/jvm/functions/Function0.invoke ()Ljava/lang/Object; (itf)
    POP
   L1
    LINENUMBER 6 L1
   L2
   L3
   L4
    ICONST_0
    ISTORE 0
   L5
    LINENUMBER 7 L5
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Math.random ()D
   L6
   L7
    LINENUMBER 6 L7
   L8
    POP2
   L9
    LINENUMBER 9 L9
    RETURN
   L10
    LOCALVARIABLE $i$a$-run-TestKt$main$2 I L5 L7 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

So, indeed:

- Calling via `()` calls a generated `Function0`-derived class that encapsulates the block as a lambda (label `L0`)
- Calling via `run` fully inlines the block (label `L5`)